# Calculate the number of times an angle must be repeated for it to complete a full rotation and for it close

Tags: matlab, math, octave

I'm trying to calculate the number of times an angle must be repeated to make a full rotation and become closed.

Example:
The internal angle of a pentagon is **108 degrees** and it must repeat **5 times** to complete a rotation and it closes at **540 degrees**.  It closes a 540 degrees because that's when all the sides meet and close.  http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/interior-angles-polygons.html

How can I calculate these numbers for arbitrary angles like **72 degrees** or **117 degrees**, etc..

Does anyone know of a way to calculate this

Ps: I'm using matlab/octave
thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math.

Comment: @woodchips it's stackoverflow and I'm using matlab and octave to program this.   Type in math in the search for stackoverflow and see what you get.

Comment: @RickT This question is more about solving a mathematical problem rather than dealing with a programming issue. Also: why is 540 considered a full cycle? Isn't it one and a half?

Comment: @Eitan T it's 540 degrees because that's when the sides become closed
http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/interior-angles-polygons.html

Comment: @RickT Please refine the question to make it clearer.

Comment: The mathisfun article you link to has the formula for finding the angle given the number of sides.  Use algebra to rearrange the equation such that the number of sides variable is all by itself on one side... and that's your formula! You'll have to do some thinking about what a non-integer number of sides represents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this question is more about solving a mathematical problem rather than a programming issue, the solution is as follows:

For a polygon with *n* sides, each internal angle *θ* equals to:

> *θ* = (*n* - 2)⋅180° / *n*

Extracting *n* yields:

> *n* = 360° / (180° - *θ*)

An arbitrary angle will not necessarily produce an integer result, so you need to find the [*least common multiple*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple). In MATLAB you can do this:

```
n = lcm(360, 180 - angle) / (180 - angle)
```

For example, this gives `n = 5` for 108°, `n = 10` for 72° and `n = 40` for 117°.